# How do I add data to a cell with the batch_update_spreadsheet method in the google sheets api?

Tags: ruby, google-sheets-api

The following code is supposed to add text to a cell on a google sheet, but when I run it, it does nothing and does not give an error:

```
values = [{formatted_value: "Hello Sheet"}]

start = {sheet_id: 0, column_index: 0, row_index: 1}
rows = [{values: values}]

requests.push({
    update_cells: {
        fields: "*",
        start: start,
        rows: rows
    }
})


body = {requests: requests}
result = $service.batch_update_spreadsheet($spreadsheet_id, body, {})
find_replace_response = result.replies[1].find_replace
puts "#{find_replace_response.occurrences_changed} replacements made."
```

Comment: Oops. Those last two lines aren't really relevant.

Comment: I think the problem might be that formatted value is read-only as it says here: (https://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/SheetsV4/CellData#formatted_value-instance_method)  If that is the case, the API should return an error saying I tried to write to a read only field instead of doing nothing.